# Live555 "testWAVAudioStreamer" stream raw pcm a-law audio (no file header)

Tags: c++, rtsp, pcm, low-level, live555

I want to stream raw pcm a-law audio file with live555 libary.
The file doesn't contains header like wav file has.
I tried to stream it using [testWAVAudioStreamer.cpp](https://github.com/rayl/live555/blob/master/testProgs/testWAVAudioStreamer.cpp) but it didn't work. (error of unsupported file).

I can play the audio file using ffplay like that:
`ffplay -f alaw -ar 8k audio_file`

How can i stream this file using testWAVAudioStreamer?